# Update counter on buttonpress

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run the code below it doesn't update the variable _counter more than once. The printed value is always "1" no matter how many times I press the button. How do I get it update everytime btnOK is beeing pressed?

```
public partial class test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected int _counter;
    public test2()
    {
        _counter = 0;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["cnt"] = 0;
    }
    protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _counter = (int)Session["cnt"];
        _counter++;
        Session["cnt"] = _counter;
        lblInfo.Text = _counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a classical situation/scenario of why state management is needed in `ASP.NET`.

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) is stateless because it runs over [http](/questions/tagged/http) protocol which itself doesn't maintain any state and so every time you press a button a new http-post request gets generated -> your `_counter` gets initialized to 0 -> gets incremented to 1 and displayed accordingly.

Consider using any state management mechanism to resolve this. You can use `Session` to avoid this like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        Session["cnt"] = 0;
    else
        DoIncrement();
}

protected void DoIncrement()
{
    if(Session["cnt"] != null)
    {
        int _counter = (int)Session["cnt"];
        _counter++;
        Session["cnt"] = _counter;
        lblInfo.Text = _counter.ToString();    
    }  
}
```

Comment: `Session["counter"]` may work for this, or even a `QueryString`. Sessions do, however, use memory.

Comment: Omg, you are so right! I can't believe why I couldn't realize this! I dont now how to implement this in c# though. I've updated my question where I've included your code (and declared it in Page_Load) but I don't get it to work. Can you take a quick look?

Comment: The code in this answer will work. Remove the external _counter declaration and use this exact code. BTW the session will carry over to any other pages as well.

Comment: NP and do as well say Thanks to @AndrewGrinder for providing a nice code edit. Thanks Andrew, much appreciated.